# How to build redux-form with source maps?

Tags: npm, webpack, redux-form

What would be needed to build redux form so that I could step into the code and see the un minified code in chrome ?

I tried building a local version and linking it into my project with `npm link` but I continue to see the babel build output instead of clean source files. I also tried adding  `devtool: 'source-map',` to the `webpack.config.js` but that did not seem to work.

I'm using redux-form 7.0.1

https://github.com/erikras/redux-form

Answer (score 0):

I wish I knew. I had to debug a problem today by building and copying `redux-form/es/*` to my `proj/node_modules/redux-form/es` dir manually after every build.

If you can find a library that supports this, I would be glad to copy however they are accomplishing it, but it's my understanding that, with the way babel library packaging works, this is just not possible.

Please ping me on twitter if you find a solution.